# Mongoose - Populate not filtering correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I want to only return the friend objects in the array where the status is "active". Yet, when I do the get request, I am still seeing friends with status "pending".

Here is my index controller:

```
index: function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({
      _id: req.params.id
    })
    .populate({path: "roommates", match: {status: {$eq: "active"}}})
    .exec(function(err, user) {
      console.log(user.roommates);
    })
  }
```

Here is the result logging to the console:

```
[ { _id: 57f2e5e02d58f51a8284bc11,
    balance: 0,
    requests: [],
    status: 'pending' } ]
```

Here is my user model for reference:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please enter a username"],
    minlength: [6, "Username must be at least 6 characters"],
    maxlength: [15, "Username cannot exceed 15 characters"],
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please enter a password"],
    minlength: [6, "Password must be at least 6 characters"],
    maxlength: [17, "Password cannot exceed 17 characters"],
  },
  roommates: [{roommate: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", unique: true}, status: {type: String, default: "pending"}, requests: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Request"}], balance: {type: Number, default: 0}}]
})
```

I only want to return friends with a status of "active". Any help?
Thanks!

Comment: Where is 'User' schema or it refer self schema in roommates??

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking? Where is User schema? It's above in the bottom code block.

Answer (score 0):

As the reference is at roommate in the user schema, the population should be:

```
    .populate({path: "roommates.roommate"})
```

and the result should look like:

```
[ { roommate: [Object], //populated object
    balance: 0,
    requests: [],
    status: 'pending' } ]
```

Now, even if you do:

```
.populate({path: "roommates.roommate", match: {status: {$eq: "active"}}})
```

It should return null:

```
[ { roommate: null,
balance: 0,
requests: [],
status: 'pending' } ]
```

Because you are populating user in roommate and user schema has no status or balance field. Status and balance are additional fields in roommate object inside roommates array.

Match works when fields are part of the schema of the referred object.

An option is to remove the status and balance fields from roommates and make them part of the user schema.

However, with this same design you can use filtering as length of roommates will hardly ever exceed 10 and this will be very minor processing.

```
    User.findOne({
    _id: req.params.id
     })
    .exec(function(err, user) {
        user.roommates = user.roommates.filter(function (rm) {
            return rm.status == "active"
        });
        console.log(user.roommates)
    })
```

Comment: Thank you but this cannot work because the status is indicative of a status of a certain roommate relationship. For instance, one user will have many status's, one for each corresponding roommate of that user. Therefore, making status a property will not work. I had to filter the data in front end angular, which worked just fine.

Comment: In your case another collection "roommate" would be appropriate. It will have status and members fields. members will be an array that will contain ids of two users so it will take care of many to many relations from both ends. Users A and B will have one roommate document with a status.